# Has monogamy or eka patni vrata, as followed by Sri Rama, origins in Vedic Culture?

Tags: rama, rig-veda

Rig Veda [III.7.4](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv03007.htm) says

> mahi tvāṣṭramūrjayantīrajuryaṃ stabhūyamānaṃ vahato vahanti |
> vyaṅghebhirdidyutānaḥ sadhastha ekāmiva rodasī ā viveśa ||

Translation of H.H. Wilson is as follows:

> The flowing rivers  invigorating him, bear along the great son of
> TWASTHRI, the undecaying upholder (of the world) radiant with various
> forms in the vicinity (of the firmmament): AGNI is associated with
> heaven and earth, as (a husband with) ***only one wife***.

---

It appears that monogamy or eka patni vrat, which was practiced by Sri Rama, has **roots in Vedic Culture**.

Am I right?